# ng-if in select option selected tag

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

I am developing Angular JS application and I want to make a select option like below.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="rc.status" ng-init="rc.status=1">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Active</option>
    <option value="0" selected="">Inactive</option>
</select>
```

I want to make active when the ng-model rc.status becomes 1 and inactive when 0.

How can I do that without doing ng-repeat.

Because I generating this view from laravel and binding the html with Angular js

Comment: What do you want to do? that mean what will happen when you change select option?

Comment: you can display in radio button instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is example that select dropdown value as per `rc.status`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="">
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="rc.status" ng-init="rc.status=1">
    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
    <option value="1">Active</option>
    <option value="0">Inactive</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <div>Status : {{rc.status}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: not working. When I do like so, getting this in html <select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched" ng-model="rc.Status" ng-init="rc.Status=0"><option value="? number:0 ?"></option>
     <option value="1">Active</option>
        <option value="0">Inactive</option>
    </select>

Comment: Here it is working properly. please some more code to check for conflict

Answer (score 1):

This might help getting the **select**   changed.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="rc.status" ng-init="rc.status=1">
    <option value="1" ng-selected="rc.status == 1">Active</option>
    <option value="0" ng-selected="rc.status == 0">Inactive</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a controller to do that :

For exmple :

`OneCtrl` init the `status` at 1 and watch them to change the select item

```
app.controller('OneCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.status = 1;

    $scope.$watch('status', function () {
        if($scope.status == 1){
            $scope.statusSelected= '0';
        }if($scope.status == 2){
            $scope.statusSelected= '1';
        }
    });
    // Change status value
    $scope.status1 = function () {
        $scope.status = 1;
    }
    $scope.status2 = function () {
        $scope.status = 2;
    }

});
```

view :

```
<select name="" ng-model="statusSelected">
    <option value="0">Active</option>
    <option value="1">Inactive</option>
</select> <br>

<button ng-click="status1()">Status 1</button>
<button ng-click="status2()">Status 2</button>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I cant use any js controller in it. Here I want to generate the HTML for binding with Angular JS

Comment: Ok, so  what's that changes the values of `rc.status`, where in your code ?